# Updating table via PDO prepare query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been having problems trying to update a value based off a code that is received on the page.

For example:

http://example.com/register.php?code=fa82f82712d1 (not the actual code, it's always a 32-char code actually).

I start a transaction, and do an update in the following way:

```
$stmt = $stmt->prepare("UPDATE USER SET GOT_CODE = 1 WHERE CODE = :code");
```

Then do a `$stmt->execute(array(':code' => $code));` from the code gotten before.

But it never updates anything, I'm running a rowCount() (gives me '0') and closing the transaction but can't seem to get it updated.

The column type is CHAR(32) which should match with the length of the code received.

Is it possible that it's causing confusions because of the data type?

Comment: Basically you nulled the original PDO object by using `$stmt = $stmt->prepare(...`. Don't do that, it might interfere with what you're doing. Use clear names such as `$pdo` or `$connection` for PDO instances. Try to make that change, also set PDO to exception mode and use try/catch to catch any errors if you get them. The data type problem isn't the issue here, so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: you should provide a different name for the PDOStatement variable, like so `$query = $stmt->prepare("UPDATE USER SET GOT_CODE = 1 WHERE CODE = :code");`

Comment: Can you post your full code? That would make it a lot easier to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe bind the parameter before like:

```
$stmt2 = $stmt->prepare("UPDATE USER SET GOT_CODE = 1 WHERE CODE = :code");
$stmt2->bindParam(":code", $code, PDO::PARAM_STR);
if ($stmt2->execute()){
        $stmt->commit();
    } else {
        $stmt->rollBack();
    }
```

EDIT: after comment of other people. The basic is to not use

```
$stmt = $stmt->prepare("UPDATE USER SET GOT_CODE = 1 WHERE CODE = :code");
```

but to give different var name like

```
$stmt2 = $stmt->prepare("UPDATE USER SET GOT_CODE = 1 WHERE CODE = :code");
```

because otherwise the system will overwrite $stmt and not work anymore

Comment: @anp i know, but the OP says he started a transaction o_o